# What does PyCharm uses internally to do the "Sync Python Requirements"?

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, requirements.txt

So I am beginner with python project and tried different way of listing requirements file.

I tried using pip freeze > requirements.txt, but it added a lot of other packages which my project is not using as well. Probably it is listing all packages listed in the current python version.

Pycharm ide provides this UI to directly initiate the sync of the requirements file, and it does beautifully with just those packages which are being used in my project.

[image]

Pycharm itself might be using some similar commands internally right, can someone guide me on how to do all those things mentioned in the UI via command line such that it only adds packages which are imported in my project

Note: I want something similar for command line

I've tried using pip freeze, pip3 freeze

Comment: I think you are asking for enterprise code to open source.

Comment: well not exactly If you read the Note, I've clearly stated I want something similar for the command line or something that does a similar job

Comment: I mean, we need to write a custom logic to complete this requirement to make *something similar for the command line or something that does a similar job*

Comment: AFAIK, you can remove unused dependencies using `pip-autoremove` but I don't think there is any open source tool to detect unused libraries in python project.